# Change Android title bar colour *after* the activity has loaded?

Tags: android, android-layout

I change the title bar when the version of Android supports using the code posted below. But I don't seem to be able to change the colour of the title bar once the Activity has actually loaded.

See the following example:

```
activity.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.page_title);
LinearLayout ll = ((LinearLayout)activity.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.page_title_bg));
ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.page_title_bg_app_online);
```

The layout is very simplistic, only containing a background layout and a TextView to show the application's title.

I've tried setting the background resource with setBackbroundResrouce but have not been able to get the changed title to appear. I've also tried invalidating the layout after I make the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought: did you try to set background of your text view (not layout)?

Weird... Just tried and it works fine for me:

```
    boolean isTitleCustomizible;
    try {
        isTitleCustomizible = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isTitleCustomizible = false;
    }

    super.setContentView(resId);

    if (isTitleCustomizible) {
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                R.layout.title_bar);

        View root = getWindow().findViewById(R.id.toolBarRoot);
        if (root != null) {
            root.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_background_normal);
        }
    }
```

The code in onClick:

```
        private boolean toggle;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View root = findViewById(R.id.toolBarRoot);
            if (root != null) {
                if (toggle)
                    root.setBackgroundResource(0);
                else
                    root.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_background_normal);
                toggle = !toggle;
            }
        }
```

Comment: No but I do not believe it would help... The text view's layout_width is set to wrap_content

Comment: Why not? Better check and be sure than just believe :)

Comment: It works for me but only once, have you tried setting the title background from an event (like a button click)?

Comment: Thanks I will create a small test application to duplicate what is going wrong with the code :)